# Does this character  have a meaning or pronunciation?

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

I was looking for the meaning of  which appears as component of characters in several languages, and I couldnt find any. Having the meaning or pronunciation of a component it makes easier to memorize characters that component is part of. Here there is some reference to it, but it gives no meaning or pronunciation.

Does this character  have a meaning or pronunciation?

Comment: `appears as component of characters in several languages` Can you specify what characters you're talking about. Otherwise I'm going to assume you're talking about Japanese *Shinjitai*, and this probably answers your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61617/is-there-a-meaning-to-the-6-stroke-component-that-%E6%81%B5-%E5%B0%82-and-%E6%95%B7-share/61622

Comment: My font just has not this character lol. Should be very rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entry on [zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=24C14) for :

> ㈠同【邦】。
> ㈡同【叀】。

Looks like it can take the pronunciation bāng (bang1) or zhuān (zhuan1), and the meanings that are associated with both listed characters.

Answer (score 1):

it’s the first hexagram, of the book of change (易經)

https://ctext.org/book-of-changes/qian/zh

most people would treat it as a symbol, not as a character of any writing system.

䷀ (u+4dc0) in chinese, we called it “乾卦”, or just “乾”. about the meanings of it, well, . . . read the book of change, sahib

Comment: It looks like you're on a device which has rendered the actual character  U+24C14 as: ䷀ U+4DC0. I think Apple uses U+4DC0 as the default fallback for undisplayable characters, especially on mobile devices and tablets.

Comment: @Mou某, omg, on my macbook, the safari displayed it as u+4dc0  on my ipad, it’s  displayed as double u+4c10  i’ll check the effect on a window machine later 